# How to create print queue and add Forms to queue in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, printing

I want to develop an application that allow user to writes and print cheques. User should be able to create up to 5 cheques 1 by 1  and add to the queue after one cheque in created. Cheque is going to create filling a windows form. Record of current cheques in the quea should be displayed in the form and by selecting preferred one user can print a cheque  Can any one tell me how can I add a windows form to a queue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't add the form to the queue.

Create an entry form that the user fills with data, then put that data into a structure/class. That structure can then be placed in the queue. If the user later wants to edit it, you can repopulate the form with data from that structure, and save it back when they're done.

Comment: I found an article http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mgold/PrintingoutYourW2FormusingCSharpand.NET11222005034221AM/PrintingoutYourW2FormusingCSharpand.NET.aspx  Should I map this converted data into a class?

Comment: From the looks of it, the `W2Document` class contains what you need.